# Can't generate base64 string from react signature canvas in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I am working on a react project for taking a signature from users. I  am using `react-signature-canvas` to sign users. I want the signature data to be saved in the backend. So how can I change the signature canvas to base64 string? Here is my code.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import SignaturePad from "react-signature-canvas";
import offer from "./assets/offer.PNG";

const Signature = () => {
  let signPad = useRef({});
  let data = "";
  const clear = () => {
    signPad.current.clear();
  };
  const save = () => {
    data = signPad.current.toDataURL();
  };
  const show = () => {
    signPad.current.fromDataURL(data);
  };
  const imageString = ""; //I want to store it here
  return (
    <div className="p-10 flex flex-col space-y-24 font-serif justify-center items-center">
      <div className="  w-56 mt-10   ">
        <p className="flex justify-start items-start -mx-36">Your Signature</p>
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
          <SignaturePad
            canvasProps={{ widtd: 500, height: 200, className: "sigCanvas" }}
            className="border-2 border-black "
            ref={signPad}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex space-x-4 -mt-24">
        {" "}
        <button onClick={clear}>Clear</button>
        <button onClick={save}>Save</button>
        <button onClick={show}>Show</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signature;
```

**Can anyone help me change the signature canvas to base64 string?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are already almost correctly set up. Your save function uses the `signPad` reference that should give you access to the underlying canvas, but for some reason you are calling `toDataURL` method on a subobject called `current` of the canvas ref.

Try changing the content of the save function to the following and check the console for base64 string output:

```
console.log(signPad.toDataURL());
```